# Regular expression for a language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammar

I made a regular expression to match this language but I'm not sure it's right.  Perhaps someone can show me where it deviates.

The language:

$L = {a^{n} c b^{m} (cc)^{p} : n \geq 1, m \leq 1, p\geq 0}$

The expression:

$r = a a^{*} c (\lambda + b) (c c)^{*}$

Comment: It’s exactly right.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to answer I can upvote and give you accepted answer. If you want.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s exactly right. If you allow the abbreviation $a^+$ for $aa^*$, you can use that instead.